# Using || or && in the strcmp() function how it works

Tags: c

Hello so i'm new at C and i was wondering if I can do this:

```
if (strcmp(sexo,sexom)!= 0) && (strcmp(sexo,sexof) != 0)
    printf("Sexo Invalido");
```

I wanted to know if I'm doing this wrong and if so how can I do this

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: You don't use them "**in** the `strcmp" function. What does your C book tell you about logical operators? What else did you find? What is your **specific** problem? We are no tutoring service.

Comment: With these parentheses this shouldn't compile.

Comment: `if (strcmp(sexo, sexom) != 0 && strcmp(sexo, sexof) != 0)`

Comment: You can read how strcmp works anywhere, like https://reference.cs50.net/string/strcmp

Comment: i wanted it to work like this i put the right words it goes to the the next step but when i put the other word it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

It is invalid syntax.

```
if (strcmp(sexo,sexom)!= 0) && (strcmp(sexo,sexof) != 0)
    printf("Sexo Invalido");
```

It would be correctly to write instead

```
if ( (strcmp(sexo,sexom)!= 0) && (strcmp(sexo,sexof) != 0) )
    printf("Sexo Invalido");
```

or

```
if ( strcmp(sexo,sexom)!= 0 && strcmp(sexo,sexof) != 0 )
    printf("Sexo Invalido");
```

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp` returns an integer value; zero if the input strings are equivalent, non-zero otherwise.

So yes, the *result* of a `strcmp` call can be the operand of the `&&` or `||` operators:

```
if ( strcmp( sexo, sexom ) && strcmp( sexo, sexof ) )
  printf( "Sexo Invalido\n" );
```

Just make sure your parentheses match up.

Remember that `&&` forces left-to-right evaluation, and that it *short circuits* - if `a` is 0, then the result of the expression `a && b` is 0 regardless of the value of `b`, so `b` won't be evaluated at all.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by others you have a little syntax error, i.e. you miss a set of `( ... )` around the whole logical expression.

Besides that your code is fine. It says:

```
If sexo is neither sexom nor sexof then print "Invalid".
```

It is easy to test with a little program like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>  

int main()
{
    char* sexom = "Male";
    char* sexof = "Female";
    char sexo[10];

    strcpy(sexo, "Male");
    if ((strcmp(sexo,sexom)!= 0) && (strcmp(sexo,sexof) != 0))
        printf("Sexo Invalido %s\n", sexo);

    strcpy(sexo, "Female");
    if ((strcmp(sexo,sexom)!= 0) && (strcmp(sexo,sexof) != 0))
        printf("Sexo Invalido %s\n", sexo);

    strcpy(sexo, "Child");
    if ((strcmp(sexo,sexom)!= 0) && (strcmp(sexo,sexof) != 0))
        printf("Sexo Invalido %s\n", sexo);

    return 0;
}
```

which will print:

```
Sexo Invalido Child
```